# upload files to google drive without logging in

Tags: python, google-drive-api

So with the google sheets api, I can use a credentials json file to edit a google sheet. I don't have to login again and again. Is it possible to do this same thing with the google drive api? I am making a Python webapp, and it is very inefficient to need to log into a google account every time I want to upload a file. I plan on only uploading files to one drive, and not multiple accounts. I have looked on stack overflow a couple times, and can only find documentation on how to login with a user account and this requires I login every time.

Best wishes,

Jake

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing as in Sheets, follow the official Python [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) from the docs for instructions on how to do it.

Comment: The quick start seems to show how to make a program that allows a user to login. I cannot seem to find a way to use a service account instead of having a user login. I need a way to use the api without using credentials that expire.

Comment: How are you doing it for Sheets? The API library is the same, it just sends it to a different service. So the same methods should generally work.

Comment: This is how I access the google sheet. https://pastebin.com/UMnhX0A3

I just share the spreadsheet with the email of the service account, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: gotcha, you are using an unofficial library. Give me a bit and I'll look into it more.

Comment: So you need to follow the instructions for using the OAuth2.0 library. If you look [here](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/__init__.py) you can see how `gspread` is just wrapping it. You should be able to break down the code they use to authenticate because this `gspread` is just an abstracted version fo the standard api library by Google. It's far too much work for me to go back through and deconstruct then reconstruct it for you but that should help you get going.